# How to load image from a url without image extension

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, uiimageview, android-imageview, android-glide

The following image url

https://via.placeholder.com/150/771796

Its working in browser, but from picasso and glide i am not able to load the image into my imagview.

Answer (score 0):

You have to resize image in this size load failed.